# Why sometimes compiler in Visual Studio C++ project do not recompiles changed functions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2017 which includes around 20 .cpp and .h files and some libs. I've noticed when I make small changes like change initialization variable value or add some code VS compiles previous version of the project not including this changes. So I have to do Build->Clean, then Build whole project which takes time.

Why is it happening? As I understand VS Compiler supposed to detect changes and rebuild associated dependencies?

Comment: If you enable minimal rebuild? If so, [minimal rebuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gm-enable-minimal-rebuild?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) determines whether C++ source files that include changed C++ class definitions (stored in header (.h) files) need to be recompiled.

If you just change the contents of a non-inline function but the signature remains the same, the Visual C++ toolchain can sometimes avoid recompiling things, even though they included a file that changed.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT didnt know about this option, looked it up in my project and it is not enabled.

Comment: It seems a issue. I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.